# Iterate over an array of one type and copy only specific items in another array of another type

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

In typescript, I have two arrays:

```
interface IFirst{
    name: string;
    age: number
}

interface ISecond {
    nickName: string;
    lastName: string;
}   

myFirstArray: IFirst[];
mySecondArray: ISecond[];

myFirstArray = [
    {name: 'tim', age: 20},
    {name: 'jim', age: 30}
]
```

How can I iterate through myFirstArray and set all names to nickNames in mySecondArray? 
Something like:

```
this.myFirstArray.forEach((element: IFirst) => {
        this.mySecondArray.push({nickName = element.name});
      })
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's clear what you want here. What is the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to assign only `nickname`, then you need to make lastname as optional in `ISecond` interface like `lastName?: string` and interface will be,

```
interface ISecond {
  nickName: string;
  lastName?: string;
}
```

You can use [**this.myFirstArray.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and assign nickname value as `myFirstArray` element name to `this.mySecondArray` like,

```
this.mySecondArray = this.myFirstArray.map((element: IFirst) => {
  return { nickName: element.name };
});

console.log("this.mySecondArray ", this.mySecondArray);
```

> [**Working code in Stackblitz...**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-itwkq4) (Take a look at console)..

Answer (score 2):

Here you have `mySecondArray` is of type array `ISecond`. So whenever you want to assign values in it you should assign both properties of the object.

Like below -

```
this.myFirstArray.map((element: IFirst) => {
  this.mySecondArray.push({nickName = element.name, lastName: ''});
})
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand that. This just was't in my focus with this problem so I forgot to write it,

Comment: It is working in combination of `Maniraj Murugan` and `porgo` answers

Comment: That's really great.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` method:

```
this.myFirstArray = [
    {name: 'tim', age: 20},
    {name: 'jim', age: 30}
];
this.mySecondArray = this.myFirstArray.map(({name, age})=> <ISecond><any>{ 
    nickname: name,
    lastName: ''
    });
console.log(this.mySecondArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize second array:

```
mySecondArray: ISecond[] = [];
```

and then push elements:

```
this.myFirstArray.forEach((element: IFirst) => {
    this.mySecondArray.push({nickName: element.name, lastName: ''});
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this was it.Although I used map